# go get | package appengine: unrecognized import path "appengine"

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have a package hosted on github which uses appengine sdk . When I do `go get github.com/myself/mynicepackage` I get an error

```
package appengine: unrecognized import path "appengine"
```

Question : How can I get this package using go get ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to download it via `go get`.

`go get` works with source code repositories, but Google App Engine SDK is provided via .zip archives.

The only possible way to get Google App Engine SDK is to download it from [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Go) and install it manually.